# Execute RequestDispatcher after 5 seconds

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I use jsp and servlets and I would like to execute a RequestDispatcher after 5 seconds.

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/page.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Is there some kind of `wait.time(5000)`?

edit: I still would be interested in a solution!

Comment: This seems like an ugly thing to do to your users (and your server). What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I want just a simple rediraction to a new website after!! few seconds. Like 3,2,1, new website

Comment: The conventional way to do this is with a bit of javascript in the browser

Comment: i still haven't found what i'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

Simply use Thread.sleep(5000) or the below approach

```
new java.util.Timer().schedule( 
        new java.util.TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // your code here
            }
        }, 
        5000 
);
```

Hope this solves your expectations.

Comment: And that will not block anything, when executed on Tomcat8? It is a big Web Application and as you can assume, everything should work as fast as possible.

Comment: Have you verified this approach ?